keyof nested properties using toolbelt
I'm trying to create a type of all possible paths of a type using toolbelt
using this type :
type Test = Readonly<{
  test: {
    n_test : 2
  },
  o_test :1
  o_n_test : {
     o_n_n_test : {
        help : "hello"
     }
  }
}>

I'd like to have that :
test | test.n_test | test.o_test | test.o_n_test | test.o_n_test.o_n_n_test | test.o_n_test.o_n_n_test.help

and here is what I tried that so far :
import type { O } from 'ts-toolbelt';

export type TestKeys = O.Paths<Test>;

and it does show
["test"] | ["o_test"] | ["o_n_test"]

but so far, I'm stuck.
I tried to use S.Join<O.Paths<Test>,"."> but sadly S.Join only takes in List<Literal>  and not List<Keys>. I tried casting it using A.Cast but still no real results
I know I can achieve something similar without toolbelt, but I'd rather use it at it's best here.
if anyone has a clue, I would be glad to have a light on.

I used type-fest, but here's my approach. https://tsplay.dev/WoZKPm
